# Print not coming out good

Tags: 3d-models, ultimaker-cura

I just designed a robot in blender, and whenever I print it, it goes horribly wrong. The first print was laying down, I had supports on, Then it started to print the arm, starting with the bottom of a sphere, and the supports caused it to fly off. The second time, I printed it standing up, with supports, and the arm didn't even print, PLA got all over my build plate. How would I print this successfully? Sideways like this? [image: maybe?]

I uploaded the model to Thingiverse last night, Here's the link: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2417504

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description of the print failures, it appears that the problem is not specific to the model. If printing supports is causing parts of the model to "fly off," there may be a temperature problem or a speed problem or a combination of the two. If you have a new filament type, it may be necessary to perform test model prints to ensure you are using good settings for the filament. If you are using old filament, it may be necessary to print test models with no complex shapes to ensure that your filament will still function properly.

You say that "PLA got all over your build plate." This is another indication of a problem not related to the model position or model design or orientation.